# A "forall" quantification usage example in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am learning haskell by fp-course.
When I implement Functor for StateT, an error occurred.

```hs
-- | Implement the `Functor` instance for @StateT s k@ given a @Functor k@.
--
-- >>> runStateT ((+1) <$> (pure 2) :: StateT Int List Int) 0
-- [(3,0)]
instance Functor k => Functor (StateT s k) where
  (<$>) ::
    forall k a b s. (a -> b)
    -> StateT s k a
    -> StateT s k b
  (<$>) f st1 = StateT $ \s -> mapFunc <$> (runStateT st1 s)
          where
            mapFunc :: (a, s) -> (b, s)
            mapFunc = \(a, s) -> (f a, s)
```

The error is

```hs
src/Course/StateT.hs:48:32: error:
    • Could not deduce (Functor k1) arising from a use of ‘<$>’
      from the context: Functor k
        bound by the instance declaration at src/Course/StateT.hs:43:10-42
      Possible fix:
        add (Functor k1) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            (<$>) :: (a -> b) -> StateT s1 k1 a -> StateT s1 k1 b
    • In the expression: mapFunc <$> (runStateT st1 s)
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘\ s -> mapFunc <$> (runStateT st1 s)’
      In the expression: StateT $ \ s -> mapFunc <$> (runStateT st1 s)
Failed, modules loaded: Course.Applicative, Course.Core, Course.ExactlyOne, Course.Functor, Course.List, Course.Monad, Course.Optional, Course.State.
```

Why this happend? How to solve?

Comment: is your `forall` shadowing the outer `k`? try removing `k` from `forall` in  the type of `(<$>)`

Comment: @cafce25 You are right. Everything is OK when I remove `k` from `forall`. I can remove `k` and `s` from forall. But if I remove `a` or `b` from `forall`, compiler will complain. Could you explain what `forall` is doing here? Why this happend?

Comment: From what I recall it's introducing type variables.

Comment: And once you understand you can get the compiler to write them for you using the [DeriveFunctor extensions](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_extra.html#deriving-functor-instances) (`deriving stock Functor`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, the `forall` keyword declares fresh type variables that shadow the definitions of any existing type variables with the same names, so your instance is equivalent to:

```
instance Functor k => Functor (StateT s k) where
  (<$>) ::
    forall k1 a b s1. (a -> b)
    -> StateT s1 k1 a
    -> StateT s1 k1 b
  (<$>) f st1 = StateT $ \s1 -> mapFunc <$> (runStateT st1 s1)
          where
            mapFunc :: (a, s1) -> (b, s1)
            mapFunc = \(a, s1) -> (f a, s1)
```

In other words, even though you're *supposed* to be giving a definition of the operator `(<$>)` for the functor type `StateT s k` (since that's the instance you're in the middle of writing), you're giving the definition for a different type `StateT s1 k1`.

That's okay, though, because GHC will allow you to give an instance definition for the "wrong" type `StateT s1 k1` if it can be unified with the desired type `StateT s k`, which it can, by unifying the specific type `s` with the arbitrary type `s1` and unifying the specific type `k` with the arbitrary type `k1`.

However, that's assuming your definition type checks.  Your use of `(<$>)` on the right-hand side of your definition has type `(a -> b) -> k1 a -> k1 b` and so requires a `Functor` instance for `k1`.  But, even though GHC knows about the `Functor k` instance from the instance head, it's never heard of this `k1` type before, and you never said in your type signature that it had a `Functor` instance.  If you had instead written:

```
instance Functor k => Functor (StateT s k) where
  (<$>) ::
    forall k1 a b s1. (Functor k1) => (a -> b)
--                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- add this
    -> StateT s1 k1 a
    -> StateT s1 k1 b
  (<$>) f st1 = StateT $ \s1 -> mapFunc <$> (runStateT st1 s1)
          where
            mapFunc :: (a, s1) -> (b, s1)
            mapFunc = \(a, s1) -> (f a, s1)    instance Functor k =>
```

everything would type check fine.

To be clear, what going on in this definition is that you've told GHC you'll be defining `(<$>)` for the type `StateT s k` for the specific `s` and `k` from the instance head, but you've instead given a definition for general `s1` and `k1`, unrelated to the `s` and `k` in the instance head, and shown that as long as this new, arbitrary type `k1` has a `Functor` instance, your definition will work.  GHC takes this definition and verifies that the type `StateT s1 k1` with arbitrary `s1` and `k1` can be unified with `StateT s k` with specific `s` and `k` from the instance head.  Since it can, it accepts your definition.

That's a pretty roundabout way of giving a definition of `(<$>)` for the type `StateT s k`.  Instead, you should just use the specific `s` and `k` type variables from the instance head, and you do this by **NOT** declaring them as fresh variables in the `forall`:

```
instance Functor k => Functor (StateT s k) where
  (<$>) ::
    forall a b. (Functor k) => (a -> b)
--                       ^      ^----^--- these are fresh type vars
--                       |
--                       `--- but this is `k` from instance head
    -> StateT s k a
--            ^^^ ^-- again, fresh a
--             |
--             `-- but `s` and `k` from instance head
    -> StateT s k b
--            ^^^ ^-- fresh b
--             |
--             `-- `s` and `k` from instance head
  (<$>) f st1 = StateT $ \s -> mapFunc <$> (runStateT st1 s)
          where
            mapFunc :: (a, s) -> (b, s)
--                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                        No forall here, so `a` and `b` come
--                        from `forall a b` in previous type
--                        signature, while `s` comes from the
--                        instance head
            mapFunc = \(a, s) -> (f a, s)
```

Comment: Got it. If I shadow k, I must tell my k is a Functor.

Comment: But why I have to explicitly point out `forall a b`? Fresh `a` `b` should be implicitly forall? Is this because I continuely use `a` `b`  in `mapFunc :: (a, s) -> (b, s)`? But `s` over here is also be used without being pointed out like `forall s k` in instancing sentence. Why? I have `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` language extension.

Comment: For historical reasons, the interaction between explicit `forall`, implicit `forall` and type variable scoping is complicated.  You **can** leave out the `forall a b`, and that scopes the `s` and `k` to the instance head while adding an implicit `forall a b` for fresh `a` and `b`, but that causes the second type signature to fail because the `a` and `b` no longer refer to the `a` and `b` from the first type signature but instead get their own implicit `forall`.  This is a key difference between explicit forall (which scopes to nested signatures) and implicit forall (which doesn't).

Comment: This is all explained in the GHC manual [section 6.11.4](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html#lexically-scoped-type-variables), though it's a tough read.  Consider that it includes gems like "A scoped type variable stands for a type variable, and not for a type. (This is a change from GHC’s earlier design.)"  I dare anyone to make sense of that sentence.

Comment: Add : `s` need not explicitly pointed out, which can be directly used in `mapFunc :: (a, s) -> (b, s)` because 
https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html#class-and-instance-declarations

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is fine. But [`(<$>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) is not a part of the `Functor` contract. It's an alias defined outside the class. The `Functor` contract demands [`fmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap). If we change your implementation to use `fmap` and remove the extraneous type annotations (which are not required for `instance` declarations), we get working code without changing the actual body of your function.

```
instance Functor k => Functor (StateT s k) where
    fmap f st1 = StateT $ \s -> mapFunc <$> (runStateT st1 s)
        where mapFunc = \(a, s) -> (f a, s)
```

Comment: Actually, OP is working through [this exercise](https://github.com/system-f/fp-course/blob/master/src/Course/StateT.hs) which uses an alternative definition of `Functor` that has `(<$>)` as its class method.